# Deserializing nullable value using .NET DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize some downloaded JSON data into simple objects. I'm using the .NET DataContractJsonSerializer class.

I have one data item that seems as though it can sometimes be null, but it seems (to me) to be expressed in an odd way. Most of the time the field looks like

```
"DateOfBirth": "1971-10-05T00:00:00"
```

but if no value is present, the field in the JSON looks like this

```
"DateOfBirth": {
    "@xsi:nil": "true",
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
}
```

Is that valid? And if so, is there a way I can get DataContractJsonSerializer to deserialize it without throwing an error?

At the moment, the relevant field in the class that I'm deserializing to is simply

```
public string DateOfBirth { get; set }
```

That works fine if I get a result set where every record has a value for DateOfBirth, but as soon as I get one of those null values, it falls over:

*System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException*

*"There was an error deserializing the object of type [MyClass]. End element 'DateOfBirth' from namespace 'item' expected. Found element 'a:item' from namespace 'item'."*

PS I'm deserializing a date to a string because DataContractJsonSerializer expects dates to be formatted in some specific way, and this data isn't.

Comment: It's "valid" in the sense that that's one way of doing it if you're a lazy XML to JSON converter, but it's safe to say that no standard JSON deserializer would actually interpret that as `null`. If it's an option, it's worth going back to the source to ask them if this is *really* how they want to serialize things. Overriding this on the receiving end is inconvenient no matter what library you use.

Comment: Looks like they're serializing XML as JSON in a particularly interesting way. If you can't change the source, you'll probably have to change the way you deserialize the JSON - which is not trivial using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`. Can't you use JSON.NET (Newtonsoft) instead?

Comment: The source of the data is the UK government: http://data.parliament.uk/membersdataplatform/memberquery.aspx It does look as thought the preferred format is XML and they're doing a rather casual conversion to JSON.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a classic case of a JSON "alternative" that was just tacked on in the most straightforward way to tick a box somewhere, with no regards to actual usefulness for consumers. I'd recommend just using the XML endpoint and the standard `DataContractSerializer`, even if you use JSON in your own service(s). As the endpoint is ASP.NET, this has a much better chance of interoperating smoothly.